# PL/SQL insert date with procedure

Tags: oracle, date, plsql, insert

I want to insert date in my dates table by passing date as `('19-JUN-1997')` parameter to procedure. Could anyone give me an example how to do it? It seems that I am doing something wrong with trying to insert date by putting variable in `TO_DATE(my_var)`.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN 
p_date('14-MAR-2017');
END;
```

---

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_date(
v_date IN Dates.date1%type) IS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Dates
(date1)
VALUES
(TO_DATE(v_date ));
END;
```

Comment: Can you provide a describe of the `dates` table?  By the way, it looks like you are passing a character parameter into a procedure that is expecting a DATE data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the format of the date (e.g., dd-mon-yyyy) then the safest thing to do is make your insert statement like thus:

```
INSERT INTO Dates (date1)
VALUES (TO_DATE(v_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY');
```

In order for your example to work, the character string date format must be in the default date format in the database.  You can get the value of the database default format using this:

```
SELECT value
FROM   nls_session_parameters
WHERE  parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'
```

However, if the default format is changed and you are relying on it, your code will break.  It also tells the reader of the code what the date format you're expecting is.